# SOAP: Аутентификация через header

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

Всем привет!

Разрабатываю что-то вроде клиента/адаптера для DHL на JAVA. Для коммуникации они используют SOAP и предоставляют следующий WSDL: [Ссылка на DHL WSDL](https://cig.dhl.de/cig-wsdls/com/dpdhl/wsdl/geschaeftskundenversand-api/3.0/geschaeftskundenversand-api-3.0.wsdl)

Аутентификация происходит через header при каждом SOAP запросе. Для этого нужно передать поля **user** и **signature** .

Из WSDL я уже сгенерировал с помощью wsimport JAR файл. Поэтому могу использовать **AuthentificationType** класс. Проблема в том, что сервис возвращает порт типа **GKV3XAPIServicePortType**. А сам header "крепится" к запросу в binding (**GKV3XAPISOAP11Binding**) , к которому доступа в коде почему-то не имею.

Могу лишь оперировать типом **GKV3XAPIServicePortType**, где нет header.

Как в этом случае происходит аутентификация? Как привязать класс **AuthentificationType** к запросу?